# Products & Orders Table Structure in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, e-commerce

I am designing a database for an eCommerce system and I am just stuck with a scenario provided with a situation. I am thinking that if site administrator deletes a product from the backend then all the associated orders with that product will also be deleted. What is the best way to prevent that happening if a product gets deleted, then it should not disturb the previous orders as we have to display the product detail in the order as well which is being fetch from the products table.

These are the three tables currently I have and the foreign key relationships are established as well.

```
Products

| product_id | name       |
| 1          | iphone 5s  |
| 2          | Samsung S3 |
| 3          | iphone 6s  |

Orders

| order_id   | customer_id   |  datetime   |
| 1          | 12            |  2015-08-15 |

Order_Product

| order_product_id   | order_id   |  product_id   |  qty | price  |
| 10                 | 1          |  2            | 1    | 300.00 |
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Few options..

1> Deletion of products should not really delete the rows, but just mark the products as deleted. - PREFERRED OPTION

2> You can use a surrogate key in the products table as the primary/unique key which the orders table refers to. When the product row is deleted (if mandatory) then use the option "on delete set null" for the foreign key. Here the use of surrogate key is just to prevent any key information loss in the orders table.